# Why wont this print "Welcome to Ruby!"

Tags: ruby

I'm following the Ruby course on Codeacademy and it's asking me to create a method, named welcome, that puts "Welcome to Ruby!" After defining the method, call it. Here's my code:

```
def welcome()
 puts "Welcome to Ruby!"
end
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: It does work. How are you calling it?

Comment: btw you do not need the () after the method definition. but @MikeCampbell is completely right, it should definitely work.

Comment: @MikeCampbell I'm still fairly new to Ruby, and I know I'll sound stupid asking, but how would I call it?

Comment: Just call it by typing its name somewhere :)

Comment: Think of defining a method as writing down a phone number. You have it but it doesn't do you any good unless you actually do something with it... like call it. =)

Answer (score 10):

You need to actually call the method after:

```
def welcome
  puts "Welcome to Ruby!"
end

# Call it
welcome
```

Answer (score 2):

What you've done so far is create a function that does something, but you're never calling that function. Functions and methods don't do anything by themselves until called / invoked.

I don't know what this tutorial you're following entails but more than likely you're missing that invocation line, which can probably go at the end of the file that contains this function:

```
# your function definition here...
welcome()
```